# Look for duplicate values in a String[] without using Sets, Lists, ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say we have this array: `String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c", "a"};`

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicate String (In this case `"a"`) and add its value to another String[] called duplicates. When the duplicate is added to the "duplicates" array, the amount of times it occured wrongfully in the array arr1 is concatenated next to it. (`recurredValue + amount`) so in this example it would be `a 1`. I have searched for this before and all of them included usage of Lists, ArrayLists, or Sets. Please do not use any of them.

Comment: What's wrong with using collections?

Comment: _"Please do not use any of them."_ No, you have to

Comment: You can do it without, you just need huge array sizes and lots of extra code.

Comment: What code have you already tried? This site is not a site where we are supposed to be doing your homework for you.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:-

```
public static String[] removeDuplicates(String[] numbersWithDuplicates) {

    // Sorting array to bring duplicates together
    Arrays.sort(numbersWithDuplicates);

    String[] result = new String[numbersWithDuplicates.length];
    String[] duplicate = new String[numbersWithDuplicates.length];
    String previous = numbersWithDuplicates[0];
    result[0] = previous;
    int counter=1;
    int duplicateCounter=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numbersWithDuplicates.length; i++) {
        String ch = numbersWithDuplicates[i];

        if (previous != ch) {
            result[counter++] = ch;
        }
        else
        {
            duplicate[duplicateCounter++]=ch;
        }
        previous = ch;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Duplicate Values are ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < duplicate.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(duplicate[i]);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this you can use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "a"};
      String[] duplicates = new String[arr1.length];
      boolean d = false;
      int count = 0;
      String dup = "";
      for(int i = 0;i < arr1.length;i++){
          count = 0;
          dup = "";
          d = false;

          for(int j = 0;j < arr1.length;j++){
              if(i != j){
                  if(arr1[i].equals(arr1[j]) && !arr1[i].equals("")){
                      arr1[j] = "";
                      d = true;
                      count++;
                      dup = arr1[i];

                  }

              }
          }
          if(d){
          duplicates[i] = dup + count;
          d = false;}

      }
      for(int k = 0;k < duplicates.length;k++)
      System.out.println(duplicates[k]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution is to create 2 arrays and have one hold the unique strings and the other its integer counter.  As you index through your sample string array, add the unique strings and increment the incidents.  This is not a very elegant or efficient solution but it should work.